# English Meaning for Abreviations (Easy Question)

Tags: star, notation

I see a lot of publications where they use "code"/abbreviations but don't give the Laymans equivalents.  Take https://academic.oup.com/view-large/127773013 from https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/483/2/2300/5184501?login=false

The columns are :-

```
HD 
Effective Temperature (Kelvin)
Radius (Solar Radius)
Solar Luminosity(?)
Mass (Solar Mass)
Unknown
Unknown
Age(?)
```

What are the unknown columns, am not clued up enough to copy the notation?

I have found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_astronomy_symbols but those above I can't find

If anyone knows of anywhere which explains these codes, that'll be awesome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of the symbols that are confusing you *are* in the Wikipedia page you link to. In columns 3, 4, and 5 are solar units: $R_{\odot}$ = solar radii, $L_{\odot}$ = solar luminosities, and $M_{\odot}$ = solar masses.

Column 6 is the [surface gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_gravity) of the star, while column 7 is the age of the star (as pointed out by James K, this should read “log(t/yr)”, not “log(t/Gyr)”). I believe the surface gravities are in cgs units = cm s$^{-2}$ (or, more precisely, the base 10 logarithm of that), since that is mentioned in section 5.2.1 of the paper.

Section 6.3 of the paper describes $\tau$ (column 8) as the "fractional main sequence age", which I assume means something like "how far along in its main sequence lifetime the star is", where 0 = zero-age main sequence (just started fusing hydrogen in its core) and 1 = about to leave the main sequence.

Note that it is standard in astronomy papers to use *base 10* logarithms rather than natural logarithms, so "log" means $\log_{10}$.

Comment: The ones that were confusing where "Unknown" or had (?) by them, probably didn't explain that well.  Thanks for clarifying what I didn't understand.  Is there a notation for "rotational velocity" ?

Comment: HD 12446 (ALF PSC B) is 330 Myr according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_Piscium but on the table, its 8.77 Gyr, do I need to apply something to the table to get 330?  Or have I made a mistake?

Comment: as noted in another question, The table has the logarithm of the age (in years, not gigayears). you need to apply "10-to-the-power" of 8.77.  it should be log(t / yr) not log t/Gyr

Comment: @JamesK Thanks for pointing that out; I’ve updated my answer accordingly.